# UITableViewCell not sizing properly on iPhone X running iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I have a `UITableViewCell` containing only a label inside it. The label is constrained to all the margins of the cell (top, bottom, trailing and leading). It is a multiline label (lines = 0) and has some static text, which will occupy multiple lines on the iPhone X's screen in both landscape and portrait.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdfp1.png) of the IB with the constraints.

[image]

Number of rows is set in code to 30. (Enough cells to always occupy the screen)

I have implemented all of the above in a new project. Most of it is done on the IB and the `UITableViewController` subclass only contains two methods, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt indexPath`. The project was created on Xcode 9 with Swift 4 and the device is running on iOS 11.2.

Heres the code for the `UITableViewController` subclass

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

When the VC first launches, all the cells are sized properly. On rotating the device to landscape, the cells resize as expected. Now, when I rotate the device back to portrait the **cells occupy a larger height than they should**.

**This only occurs on the iPhone X**. The cells are laid out as expected on all other iPhones.

Also, this does not happen on any of my older projects (created using Xcode 8).

[When the VC launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHYK.png)

[After rotating to landscape and back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhs3.png)

[image: before] [image: after]

I have been trying replicate all the attributes from my older project, but it still doesn't size properly.

Any input would be appreciated...
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As Brandon pointed out, it only occurs when a `UITableViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. A `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` embedded inside a `UINavigationController` shows the correct behavior. And a `UITableViewController` outside a `UINavigationController` also behaves as expected.

Comment: No code, no answer.. We cannot guess what is happening in your code.. At least provide a sample so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the IB and the code to go along with it. This should provide you with enough information to recreate what I'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I am able to reproduce this 100% of the time.. It's super weird because if the `UITableViewController` is NOT embedded inside a `UINavigationController`, then everything works.. the second it's embedded, it exhibits the behaviour shown in your post..

To fix it, I did:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .automatic)
}
```

It works, but it's not ideal reloading all the time.. Haven't found another solution to this yet.. So far it only happens with `UITableViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController`.. Doesn't happen with `UITableView` inside `UIViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController`.. It's very specific to Table Controller.

That seems like a bug to me.. I went through almost all the storyboard parameters and haven't found any solutions.

Comment: I agree; it sounds like a bug in UIKit.

Comment: Should this be treated as a bug and reported to apple?

Comment: I have a tableview in UIViewController embeded in UINavigationController, when rotate in iPhonex, the tableview's header disappears, the delegate method titleForHeader not called.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
}
```

may help in similar cases.

I do not know details, but it might be bug in UIKit that causes layout margins to become incorrect due to safe area (which is currently special on iPhone X).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. The cells in the UITableView were changing height when scrolling, but only on iPhone X.

The issue is clearly related to the safe area of the iPhone X. My table cells contain a collection view - and the collection view cell in storyboard/interface builder had these two safe area boxes checked (probably by default):

[image: storyboard boxes to uncheck]

Unchecking them, caused the constraints to use "superview" intead of the "safe area" and the table cells no longer resized when scrolling.